# Bash script that connects to server using ssh

Tags: bash, ssh

I am trying to write a bash script that will allow me to login using ssh connection.
The condition is that the password is stored into a .txt file.

I need to write a bash script that will automatically request a connection to

```
   ssh USER@example.net -p 733
```

and automatically will use the passwords that are stored into a .txt file

I never wrote something in bash. Can someone help me.
Thank you in advance for your time.

Comment: Please look into using private key fiels instead of passwords stored in files. Easier to use and generally a lot safer than hacks like these

Comment: @Wolph how private key is related to my question. Thank you.

Comment: You can use them instead of passwords

Comment: @Wolph In my case i need to have a function written in bash that will take passwords from .txt file and input them while connecting to ssh server

Comment: Wolph is right. By the way, you can use `expect`  http://linux.die.net/man/1/expect

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't do it with plain `bash` script. You need to use `expect` command.

Having said that **it is really a very bad idea to have a password stored in a text file**, here is how you can do it using `expect`:

```
#!/usr/bin/expect

set timeout 20
set f [open "password.txt"]
set password [read $f]
close $f

spawn ssh user@host
expect "user@host's password:"
send $password
interact
```

Still I suggest to follow @Wolph's advice to look into using a pair of keys when accessing a remote server using `ssh`.

Comment: it might be a bad idea, but then again, it might not be a big deal at all to have a password in plaintext. At work we are constantly ssh-ing into embedded devices during development. The devices all have the same default password, it's even published on our web pages. To save time we scripted ssh commands and it's no big deal. That being said, in general, it is a very bad idea. +1 for expect though. I've seen this many times and everyone is basically just saying "keys".

Comment: Everyone is saying "keys" because in the time it takes you to write a script that can read a password from a file and use it with `ssh`, you could have generated the key pair and copied the public key to the remote servers.

Comment: @buff First of all I would like to thank you for your code, it's really very nice one, I never had experience with bash/expect scripts. Now I have another, and I hope last issue. In the .txt file were i keep the password for the ssh connection I have more then one, and only 1 works. How can I loop in a such a way that the script will take all the words from .txt file and try  as a password in this script. Thank you

Answer (score 1):

i suggest you to use password less authentication it will be more secure follow these steps :

```
example@example:~/bash$ ssh-keygen -t rsa
Generating public/private rsa key pair.
Enter file in which to save the key (/home/example/.ssh/id_rsa): ## the directory which located private key and public key.
Enter passphrase (empty for no passphrase): ## you can use passphrase password if you want .
Enter same passphrase again: ## enter same password again.
Your identification has been saved in /home/example/.ssh/id_rsa.
Your public key has been saved in /home/example/.ssh/id_rsa.pub.
The key fingerprint is:
70:03:68:70:0a:52:16:55:55:66:62:2b:51:67:81:92 example@example
The key's randomart image is:
+--[ RSA 2048]----+
|o.=+oo++=oB.     |
|.o oo E+.B       |
|  ..  o.+        |
|       + .       |
|        S        |
|                 |
|                 |
|                 |
|                 |
+-----------------+
```

then type

```
scp -o Port=733 ~/.ssh/id_rsa.pub USER@example.net:/home/example/.ssh/authorized_keys
```

- then it will ask you first time for your remotely server for latest
  time
- now if you type `ssh -p 733 USER@example.net`  you don't need to put
  any password again that's it password less authentication more secure than any script.