# How to save remote server password in a Shell Script?

Tags: bash, shell

I wrote a simple shell script to backup SQL database and send a copy of the backup file to a remote server using the following command:

```
scp /root/backup.sql root@0.0.0.0:/root
```

Each time I run the script I should enter the remote server password manually. How can I save the remote server password on the script so it copy the file automatically?

Comment: Please don't do this. Your remote server shouldn't even allow logging in remotely as root, let alone using a password that's saved to disk on a different host.

Comment: (Instead, you should have a specific, passwordless user with permissions to write the backup, and your script should use certificate-based authentication.)

Comment: Either certificate or plain public-key auth would be appropriate; otherwise, I completely agree with @ruakh.

Comment: The advice above is solid. AND  you should learn to search here for your topic. This is a close match https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32819476/bash-script-that-connects-to-server-using-ssh/32822788 . I won't vote to close as a duplicate because my bash superpower ;-> will close your Q. I leave here for others to vote also. Good luck

Comment: Thanks for the recommendations. I know it is not a good idea but I just want a working solution for this.